# How to execute python file in linux

Tags: python, linux

I am using linux mint, and to run a python file I have to type in the terminal: `python [file path]`, so is there way to make the file executable, and make it run the `python` command automatically when I doublr click it?

And since I stopped dealing with windows ages ago, I wonder if the .py files there are also automatically executable or do I need some steps.

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to add a shebang. A shebang is the first line of the file. Its what the system is looking for in order to execute a file.

It should look like that :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or the real path

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

You should also check the file have the right to be execute. `chmod +x file.py`

As Fabian said, take a look to Wikipedia : [Wikipedia - Shebang (en)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

Comment: Use the /usr/bin/env method instead of a fixed path. This will play nicely with virtualenv when someone (possibly you in the future) will want to execute your file with a different version of Python than the default on the system.

Answer (score 13):

I suggest that you add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

instead of `#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of the file. The reason for this is that the python installation may be in different folders in different distros or different computers. By using `env` you make sure that the system finds python and delegates the script's execution to it.

As said before to make the script executable, something like:

```
chmod u+x name_of_script.py
```

should do.

Answer (score 8):

yes there is. add

`#!/usr/bin/env python`

to the beginning of the file and do

`chmod u+rx <file>`

assuming your user owns the file, otherwise maybe adjust the group or world permissions.

.py files under windows are associated with python as the program to run when opening them just like MS word is run when opening a .docx for example.

Answer (score 8):

1.save your file name as hey.py with the below given hello world script

```
#! /usr/bin/python
print('Hello, world!')
```

2.open the terminal in that directory

```
$ python hey.py
```

---

or if you are using python3 then

```
$ python3 hey.py
```

---

Answer (score 7):

Add to top of the code,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then, run the following command on the terminal,

```
chmod +x yourScriptFile
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this at the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

This is a shebang. You can read more about it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).

After that, you must make the file executable via

```
chmod +x your_script.py
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have python 3 installed then add this line to the top of the file:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
```

You should also check the file have the right to be execute. chmod +x file.py

For more details, follow the official forum:

[https://askubuntu.com/questions/761365/how-to-run-a-python-program-directly](http://Official%20thread)

Comment: I think you are missing the # to complete the shebang.
Should be #!/usr/bin/env python3