# how to execute .py script from bash shell

Tags: python, bash, shell

I open a terminal and cd into my documents where I have my .py file called trianglearea.py which is a very basic program that I am trying to execute. 
I type /Documents$ python trianglearea.py into the shell and nothing happens; bash prompts me for another command as if what I just prompted doesn't exist. I try ./trianglearea.py but I get a syntax error because I have not entered interactive python and bash doesn't understand my python script. If I go to the file gui style and double click and say run in terminal a window flashes and disappears but that is not what I want. I want to have my little program run in interactive python so I can enter stuff and actually use my function.
This is all I have in the.py file

```
def area(base,height):
    ''' (number, number) - number
    Return area of a triangle with dimensions base * height

    >>>>area(10,5)
    25.0
    '''
    return base*height/2
```

I know this shouldn't be that hard but it has stumped me.

Comment: Your script doesn't do anything. So what you're seeing when running `python thing.py` is perfectly normal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933169/how-to-execute-python-file-in-linux/13933251#13933251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose if your script file name is `mycode.py` then you can use `python -i mycode.py`:

```
$ python -i mycode.py
>>> area(10, 5)
```

`-i`     When a script is passed as first  argument  or  the  -c
          option  is used, enter interactive mode after executing
          the script or  the  command. [**refrence**](http://www.python.org/doc/QuickRef.html)

Comment: the  python-i is exactly what I have been trying to figure out, thank you!

Comment: @arron glad if worked :)

Answer (score 7):

The reason nothing happens is because you haven't called your method in your script, so the file simply defines the method and then quits.  This is a quick fix:

```
def area(base,height):
    ''' (number, number) - number
    Return area of a triangle with dimensions base * height

    >>>>area(10,5)
    25.0
    '''
    return base*height/2

print area(10,5) # calling the method
```

The proper way to fix this is to add this check:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print area(10,5)
```

When Python scripts are run from the command line, the special variable `__name__` is set to the string `'__main__'` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) for more). That if statement essentially says, *"If I am run from the command line, execute the method area with the arguments 10 and 5 and print the results."*

Finally, to make sure your script can be run from the prompt like this `./myscript.py`, you need to tell your shell how to execute it. This is done by adding a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to the top of your file.

Combining all that, your file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def area(base,height):
        ''' (number, number) - number
        Return area of a triangle with dimensions base * height

        >>>>area(10,5)
        25.0
        '''
        return base*height/2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print area(10,5)
```

Comment: This is great and kind answer Burhan as you, to your credit, didn't take the opportunity to sneer like some do. You deserved my upvote.