# Python script won't execute after double click, nothing happens?

Tags: python

I have just made a simple python program. I want to execute it with python 3.6.3 which I installed today. There are also available python 2.7 and 3.5 by default, their path /usr/bin/
The code looks like this:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python3.6

name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
print("Your name is " + name + " and your age is " + str(age) + ".")
print(input("Press any key to close the program: "))
```

After this I opened terminal, navigated to the folder where I saved the file.
/home/neba/PYTHON_PROJECTS and made the script executable: chmod u+x nina.py

When I tried to execute the nina.py nothing happens. I have even tried to execute it with python 3.5 and 2.7 but then an error occurred. I took the
[screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hk6OA.png) of the error.

Comment: Why do this as opposed to just `./nina.py` on the terminal?

Comment: I am new to python and in programming in general. Honestly, I have just followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933169/how-to-execute-python-file-in-linux.

Comment: on linux just do: "python3 nyna.py" from the same directory from the terminal. What is the result?

Comment: Well, it works. However, I wanted to run the script by double clicking on it, which still doesn't work, and I am not sure why nor if it is possible to preform such action [OS Linux Mint 18.2 Xfce 64bit]. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error message in your screenshot. It isn't complaining about your Python program. In fact, I would wager that you'll have the same problem with *any* kind of script you try to launch from the GUI file manager:

> Failed to execute child process
>   "xterm" (No such file or directory).

It's trying to launch `xterm`, a terminal emulator for the X Window System.

My guess is you need to either install xterm or else create a symlink to run whatever other GUI terminal emulator you do have installed.

Here is a Mint community provided [xterm package](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/xterm). Installing it may get you up and running.

If you have another terminal emulator such as xfce-terminal, you may be able to use a symlink as described in [this discussion](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=145960) (adjusting the exact commands as needed).

For more ideas, you can try a search for [linux mint xfce failed to execute child process xterm](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+mint+xfce+failed+to+execute+child+process+xterm).

If this doesn't do the trick, you might try asking in [Super User](https://superuser.com/), as this appears to be a system configuration problem, not a programming question per se.

Comment: Dear Sir, thank You very much for Your comprehensive answer. Installing xterm package https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/xterm solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the *.py files using "Python launcher" which comes handy with IDLE(Python 3.xx versions ) .