# Running a python file from file manager

Tags: python, linux

I'm having trouble figuring out how to run a python file and have the output appear in a new window.

I'm using Linux, and I can have it run perfectly fine from within the terminal, but I need to be able to run it from the file manager.

When I double click the file, all it does is open a text editor.

I've alteredthe permissions to allow the file to be executed, but double clicking still just opens the text editor.

How can I get the file to open a new window and show its' output there?

Edit: typos

Comment: make sure python file starts with a shebang line like this `#!/usr/bin/env python` if not exist add it yourself and try again

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933169/how-to-execute-python-file-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `programm` assosiate with `.py` files. e.g. to associate `.py` codes with the terminal.
This is all different in different distribution (or better Desktop Manager). Try this [other post](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/files-open.html.en)